# Azure File Share vs Managed Disk for storing shared resources and uploaded files

Tags: azure

I have 2 web servers acting as a cluster behind a loadbalancer. All pretty standard fare so far.
As the system has evolved teh re are a lot of resources that need to be available to both webservers, and the application also now needs to allow for file uploads.

I have tried to do this with a managed disk, however I cannot get both VMs to see files as they are written, it seems that the way it works (or the way I have it set up) is that they are both able to write to the disk but can only see their own resources.

I have read a number of pages and some refer to Azure File shares as the way to do this rather than by using a managed disk, but I cannot find a definitive right answer. Apologies that this is not strictly a coding problem unless you allow for the fact that I used Powershell to set up the Azure account), but as its cloud, it doesn';t seem to fit in server fault either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with Azure File Shares. I would mount File Share as a network drive on both web servers (assuming they are Azure VMs) to use standard IO libraries to read/write from the File Share.

Another advantage of using Azure File Shares is that they are also accessible via REST API. That would enable the scenario when you have to read/write files from services which do not support SMB protocol (Azure Web Apps for example) by simply using HTTP protocol.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction#key-benefits) (emphasis mine):

> Shared access. Azure file shares support the industry standard SMB and
> NFS protocols, meaning you can seamlessly replace your on-premises
> file shares with Azure file shares without worrying about application
> compatibility. **Being able to share a file system across multiple
> machines, applications/instances is a significant advantage with Azure
> Files for applications that need shareability**.

Comment: Thank you. The current project is a lift and shift from another environment, and I have been asked to do it with no code changes if at all possible, so I assume that I can just treat the azure share like another drive? (I'll read the links as well)

Comment: `so I assume that I can just treat the azure share like another drive?` - That's correct.

Comment: Thanks, if I now use explorer I can see the files int eh share. If I map it as a Virtual directory I get a 500 error that I think is a security issue. However I cannot right click on the share and add IIS Users, I get a "the program cannot deterkmine if (domain) is joined to a domain" message, so it looks like I am close, but not there

Answer (score 0):

Please see how to Share an [Azure Managed Disk documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared#:%7E:text=Azure%20shared%20disks%20is%20a%20new%20feature%20for,new%20or%20migrate%20existing%20clustered%20applications%20to%20Azure.). Currently only ultra disks and premium SSDs can enable shared disks.  You didn't specify what type of managed disk you tried.

Comment: Apologies, its a Premium SSD. However reading the documentaion,  I see this para "Shared managed disks do not natively offer a fully managed file system that can be accessed using SMB/NFS. You need to use a cluster manager, like Windows Server Failover Cluster (WSFC) or Pacemaker, that handles cluster node communication and write locking." 
So if I read that correctly, I need some other software (or config) to allow dual read / write. If so, I may be mis-using managed disks for my scenario (Centralising upload resources and common download assets)

Comment: yes after re-reading your scenario, Azure Files is the best option with the least impact to your legacy application.